# Virtual mini-Linux distribution that can be run within a unit test on Windows

Tags: java, linux, unit-testing

I would like to automate testing of some remote SSH functionality written in Java. In order to test it for real I would like to have some simple Linux distro against which the test will run. Automated tests though should be able to run on Windows machine. Probably Linux may run in some kind of virtual machine as guest OS and test class may be the one starting and stopping that.

Do any of you know of something similar to this or any alternatives to testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use VirtualBox with Ubuntu installed inside it for any such stuff. The reason being that VirtualBox is ridiculously easy to set up so the virtual machine looks like a different computer with a proper IP address for the local machine (use a "bridged" network interface), and Ubuntu is ridiculously easy and fast to set up (download the image, boot, answer 3-4 questions, walk away, come back 15 mins later).

It also lets you return to the last snapshot in case you totally screw it up.

It runs perfectly well in "seamless" mode too if compositing effects are turned off, i.e. you see the Linux Windows just like any other window on your screen, among the Windows windows.

So really, all the advantages, and hardly a disadvantage.

Comment: Thanks, looks promising, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Cygwin has been around since 1995, and would be perfect for setting up unit testing of this sort of feature under windows, since you can run an sshd in it.  See [sshd under Cygwin](http://www.noah.org/ssh/cygwin-sshd.html) and [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)

Comment: I knew about Cygwin, but its setup process is a bit complex. I hoped for something else. But anyway, thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: I use virtualbox for development.  I didn't mention it because  starting up an entire virtual machine when you want to run a unit test, which will probably take several minutes at minimum, will be hard to automate.  You'll have to deal with timing issues and figuring out how to script startup/shutdown.  In this case the overhead of Cygwin is far less, because you're starting only what you need -- the sshd, vs an entire linux server.

Comment: Starting VM from a saved state takes couple of seconds. Also I like the fact that I can reuse same VM on any other machine (Mac, Win, Linux). Also you can start VM from a command line using VBoxManage.

Comment: Yes the ability to move vm images around is really nice.  If that is something you see yourself doing that would be a major plus.  The command line VBoxManage tool is also an advantage.  One trick you can take advantage of in windows is to install the loopback adapter and use that to set a static ip you can use to talk to the vm. [link](http://www.gizmola.com/blog/blog/archives/95-Run-a-Centos-Lamp-development-server-on-XP-using-VirtualBox.html)